# Erro de sessão no httpclient android

Tags: android, cookies

Eu estou tentando fazer um aplicativo para fazer login no site da faculdade, e através de crawler eu trabalhar as informações retornadas pelo httpclient.
Obs: estou fazendo para aprendizado, comecei recentemente no java.

Faço varios posts por que o site da faculdade tem redirecionamento durante o login.

O erro é que me autentico, porem quando faço o Post da ultima página esta aparecendo no console o texto de sessão expirada.

Declarações:

```
    private AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
private PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore;
```

Código:

```
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("tipo", "aluno");
    params.put("unidade", "12");
    params.put("login", "2013200111");
    params.put("senha", "???");

    client.post("http://www.unicarioca.edu.br/gvcollege_submit.php",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String str = getString(arg2);
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                        Throwable arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("lstUnidades", "1,12");
    params.add("ViewLoginXmlXsl[method]", "btnLogin_click");
    params.add("acao", "login");
    params.add("usr", "2013200111");
    params.add("passwd", "???");

    client.post(
            "https://portal.unicarioca.edu.br/index.php5?irPage=login&irModulo=aluno",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String str = getString(arg2);
                    System.out.println(arg2);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                        Throwable arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    client.get(
            "https://portal.unicarioca.edu.br/modulos/aluno/login.php5?",
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String str = getString(arg2);
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                        Throwable arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Vou descrever passo a passo.

1° Cookie enviado pelo chrome- pagina gvcollege -- sem retorno de cookies

```
ys-path_menu_aluno=s%3A/ynode-7/ynode-36/ynode-38; _ga=GA1.3.1594079648.1403628555; __utma=127282249.1594079648.1403628555.1409943723.1410190271.40; __utmb=127282249.1.10.1410190271; __utmc=127282249; __utmz=127282249.1408118488.24.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); PHPSESSID=17d78ba1c38aafae711f916838baa997
```

Após o envio tem um redirecionamento, para index.php5?irPage=login....

2° cookie enviado pelo chrome --

```
Cookie:ys-path_menu_aluno=s%3A/ynode-7/ynode-36/ynode-38; _ga=GA1.3.1594079648.1403628555; __utma=127282249.1594079648.1403628555.1409943723.1410190271.40; __utmb=127282249.1.10.1410190271; __utmc=127282249; __utmz=127282249.1408118488.24.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
```

A página retorna o cookie setado

3° Cookie setado

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=2e1dd7378b3ef2a5a6d443c9b0128f99; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=17d78ba1c38aafae711f916838baa997; path=/; HttpOnly
```

E faz um redirecionamento para login.php5

4° cookie enviado pelo chrome para o site da faculdade

```
ys-path_menu_aluno=s%3A/ynode-7/ynode-36/ynode-38; _ga=GA1.3.1594079648.1403628555; __utma=127282249.1594079648.1403628555.1409943723.1410190271.40; __utmb=127282249.1.10.1410190271; __utmc=127282249; __utmz=127282249.1408118488.24.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); PHPSESSID=17d78ba1c38aafae711f916838baa997
```

5° Cookie setado

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=b73d66a5f917ff9615aefd469a6fe758; path=/; HttpOnly
```

6° passo ele redireciona para a home page do aluno.

Oque seriam esses cookies ys-path_menu_aluno e outros que aparecem ?
Não consegui identificar onde eles foram setados.

Comment: Lucas, esse código esta atualizado com a dica do Igor? Poderia incluir a parte de configuração do `CookieStore`?

Comment: Lucas, olhei o site da sua faculdade e percebi que as duas primeiras requests não precisam ser feitas (testei um login/senha inválidos e ele me jogou direto pra última página). A questão da sessão expirada é porque um cookie de sessão `PHPSESSID` (domínio portal.unicarioca.edu.br) se perde. Acredito que só tendo a última requisição funciona, mas poderia verificar se nas duas primeiras requisições quais cookies são retornados? Poderia também incluir na sua pergunta (limpando dados pessoais se tiver) o conteúdo deles para cada uma?

Comment: Esta atualizado com a dica sim.

Vou adicionar os cookies aqui.

Comment: O problema é que na ultima requisição não é passado nenhum parâmetro, conforme depurei o login do site no chrome.

Comment: Usando o sistema pelo browser, qual tela ele redireciona depois de logar no `https://portal.unicarioca.edu.br/modulos/aluno/login.php5?` usando o form? É a mesma página?

Comment: https://portal.unicarioca.edu.br/modulos/aluno/index.php5
                                                   Cookie:ys-path_menu_aluno=s%3A/ynode-7/ynode-36/ynode-38; _ga=GA1.3.1594079648.1403628555; __utma=127282249.1594079648.1403628555.1409943723.1410190271.40; __utmb=127282249.1.10.1410190271; __utmc=127282249; __utmz=127282249.1408118488.24.5.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); PHPSESSID=b73d66a5f917ff9615aefd469a6fe758

Comment: Eles provavelmente foram setados via javascript. Está setando esta setando o PersistentCookieStore com `AsyncHttpClient.setCookieStore`? Eu acredito que a última request não seja necessária. Porque no `POST` ele redirecionou para a home do aluno, imprima o resultado do terceiro parâmetro `byte[]` para ver.

Comment: myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);   
myCookieStore.clear();

Comment: Estou achando que meu problema esta sendo esses cookies que são setados via javascript.

Comment: Hmmm, boa constatação... Pode ser que esteja havendo algum processamento javascript que no seu caso via `HttpClient` não esta sendo feito e ai quebra o fluxo do sistema... Não só de Cookies, mas de validação/requisições ajax e etc... Uma alternativa seria investir em um `WebView` "invisível" (permitindo javascript), fazer as navegações a partir dele e fazer parse do HTML com `JSoup` por exemplo.

Comment: Boa idéia vou tentar aqui e posto, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta salvar os cookies antes usando isso.

```
PersistentCookieStore cookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(
            context);
((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Comment: PersistentCookieStore cannot be resolved to a type

vlw Igor,tentei utilizar isso porém meu eclipse não conseguiu detectar nenhuma biblioteca para esse PersistentCookieStore, qual é o pacote dele ?

Comment: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: Não funcionou o erro persistiu!!! :(